# Java Process doesn't quit

Tags: java, curl, process

I'm trying to periodically send post requests including a pic to a site. It works for the first times but then stucks. What am I doing wrong?

```
p = r.exec("curl --form api_key=<key> --form api_secret=<secret> "
           + "--form upload=@record.jpg -m 20 "
           + "http://api.face.com/faces/detect.json");

BufferedReader br = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line = "", text = "";

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    text += line + System.getProperty("line.separator");
}

System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Seems that you've forgotten to close your BufferedReader. I don't know if this will solve your problem, but leaving the stream opened might cause some other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it printing an error you cannot see. (I suggest you use ProcessBuilder to redirect error messages to std out) or the process is hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing and closing the bufferedreader before doing a new request. I never used curl, but could it be that you have to wait until the process is done before running a new one?

Comment: you really helped me a lot. The mistake was using Runtime.exec and also BufferedReader. I switched to ProcessBuilder and InputStream. Now everything is fine. Thank you to all.